# Procedimiento almacenado oracle que muestre la actualización de registros

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

lo que estoy haciendo es un procedimiento almacenado sobre la base de datos HR en pl/sql para actualizar el salario mínimo y máximo para un id específico en la tabla jobs, el procedimiento debe proveer 3 parámetros, que a continuación se los hago ver:

```
create or replace procedure upd_job_sal2(va_id in jobs.job_id%type, 
                                        min_sal in jobs.MIN_SALARY%type,
                                        max_sal in jobs.MAX_SALARY%type) 
is
begin
           update  jobs
            set job_id=va_id ,
                min_salary=min_sal,
                max_salary=max_sal
            where job_id=va_id;   

            commit;
 end;
```

Lo ejecuto:

```
set serveroutput on;
 BEGIN
 upd_job_sal2('hol',1000,2000);
 COMMIT;
  END;
```

Y solo genera un mensaje :

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda por favor.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aqui te dejo un [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: Y cual era el resultado que esperabas?

Comment: Hola gbianchi gracias por su valiosa ayuda!! lo que quiero que muestre es los registros actualizados, ya que ahì solo me muestra el mensaje...

Comment: Aun sigo esperando que alguien me ayude... por favor